# What are the primary differences between desktop and server hardware

Tags: hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Benefits of Server Hardware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58570/what-are-the-benefits-of-server-hardware)

Why are there separate product lines for Server and Desktop hardware. For example, Xeon vs Pentium, IDE vs SCSI hard drives.

What are the principles of server hardware selection that led to these product lines

Answer (score 0):

I know one main difference out there is servers usually have support for ECC (Error Correcting Code).  This allows errors in the RAM to be detected and corrected.

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that IDE and SCSI are being phased out in favor of the faster SATA2 interface.

Comment: yes I havent seen a recent server with scsi disks. but many older machines have those

Comment: SATA for IDE and SAS for SCSI, both are basically the extensions/advancements of the respective IDE and SCSI technologies.

Comment: There are also redundant/hot-swappable power supplies as well as other hot-pluggable components (expansion cards, processors, memory, etc.) which make the server "beefier" operationally. Intel also tends to disable their more advanced processor features for their "desktop" lines.

Comment: @Midhat and @Bandit - SCSI is *not* being phased out. Old *parallel* SCSI interconnects are being phased out in favor of *serial* attached SCSI a.k.a. SAS. The SCSI command set still has a ton of advantages over the ATA command set, on which both IDE and SATA are based.