# Where does the line lie between a computer and a server?

Tags: web-server

I could turn my mac into an FTP server, a file sharing server and a music sharing server.  From where I am standing, this doesn't look like it's an actual server; or is it?  A server to me is a "box" with no screen, and sits on a shelf, generally doesn't turn off

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the cons to using a PC/cheap PCs as servers vs hardware designed to be used for servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/190982/what-are-the-cons-to-using-a-pc-cheap-pcs-as-servers-vs-hardware-designed-to-be-u)

Comment: @Ben: Not a duplicate, that question was about hardware and everybody agreed what made it a server, this is about what makes something a server in the same place.

Comment: Why is my question closed instead of migrated to the correct site?

Answer (score 2):

The term "server" refers to the functionality, not the shape or position of the box. Windows servers often have attached screens with full guis (however silly of them); some servers live on desks in lobbies instead of in climate controlled racks; and last but not least some servers even [turn off now and then](https://serverfault.com/questions/258064/t)!

The line gets drawn when other computers depend on network access to a "central" one for services of any kind. That box becomes a server.